# Distinguishing files on the basis of first column's content

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have multiple tab-separated files with `.cluster` extension. I want to classify these files on the basis of their first column content using the following criteria: (`2` and `3` are actual digits/content inside the files)

- class_1: Only `2` AND `3` present on successive lines
- class_2: Only `2` present
- class_3: Only `3` present

I want to write their file names in `.txt` files with the respective class name.
How do I do it with shell scripting?

Comment: What about cases where other values are present? Or those where `2` and `3` appear but non-consecutively?

Comment: The files have been processed as such that there aren't any exceptions as the ones raised by you. So, each file would either have only two lines (line_1: 2, line_2: 3) or have only one line (line_1: 2 OR 3).

Comment: So, class 1 is "all files with two lines", and class 2 is "all files with one line that is `2`"?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Precisely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for filename in *.cluster
do
    class=$(cut -d$'\t' -f1)                      # Part 1
    if [ $(wc -l "$filename") -eq 2 ]             # Part 2, start
    then
        class=1
    fi                                            # Part 2, end
    printf '%s\n' "$filename" >> class_"$class".txt # Part 3
done
```

This has three parts:

1. By default, it classifies the file based on the first field of the only line: the `class` variable is set to whatever is in the file, up to the first tab character on each line. This will be either `2` or `3` for class 2 & 3, since those files have only one line.

   [`cut` chops files up by delimiters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html), [`$'\t'` is a Bash way of writing a tab character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), and `-f1` asks `cut` to output only the first delimited field.
2. If the file has two [lines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) (`$(wc -l "$filename") -eq 2`), it **must** be class 1, so the `class` variable is forcibly set to 1, replacing its value from step 1. The `if` ... `fi` deals with this.
3. Finally, the filename is appended to the appropriate class file: `printf '%s\n' "$filename" >> class_"$class".txt`

At the end you will have three files `class_N.txt` for each N in 1, 2, 3, with one filename per line. If any file has some *other* contents than what you outlined in the question, like a different first field or length, you will get extra class files created.

In the perverse case where a filename itself contains a newline character, this will fall apart (and give you an opportunity to reconsider your filename choices), but otherwise it should be fine.